# How to read the file's data using io.File ?

Tags: java

If i have a path of a .txt file, and i want to get all the data into one String, 
there is anyway i can do it?

I didnt found proper method in the io.File [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Comment: This has been answered a lot of times I guess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no single method that will read the entire file in java.io package, but you can quite easily do it by using a BufferedReader, reading line by line and appending them together with '\n' to get the full content. eg:

```
String  line = null;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader("c:/path/yourfile.txt");
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line).append("\n");
}  
// you may probably need to remove the last '\n' before toString()

String fileContent = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to add an [Apache Commons IO library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) to your project and use one of [FileUtils.readFileToString](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString(java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) methods

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have used the Java.util.Scanner class and had success with that. I would try writing a helper method like:

```
public String getFileAsString(String pathName){
  StringBuilder fullTxtFileAsString = new StringBuilder();
  Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(pathName));
  while(in.hasNext()){
    fullTxtFileAsString.append(in.nextLine);
    fullTxtFileAsString.append("\n");
  }
  return fullTxtFileAsString.deleteCharAt(fullTxtFileAsString.size() - 1).
    toString(); //Removes the extra newline character
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Files.readAllLines(Path file)` to read your txt file in a List, than you can use `String.join(..)` to build a single String as below::

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file.txt"));
String s = String.join( "", lines);
System.out.println(s);
```

hope this can help.